# Why does the same spring websocket client work in a desktop java application, but does not work on android?

Tags: java, android, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I write websocket client using Spring websocket :

```
WebSocketClient webSocketClient =
                new StandardWebSocketClient();
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(
          Collections.singletonList(new WebSocketTransport(webSocketClient))
);

SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

String url = "ws://localhost:8080/chat-endpoint";

StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new StompSessionChatHandler();
StompSession session = stompClient.connect(url, sessionHandler).get();
```

And it works on a desktop java application.

My goal was to make a websocket client on android, so I tried to port this code on android client :

```
public class Client {
    private StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = null;
    private StompSession session = null;
    private StandardWebSocketClient standardWebSocketClient = null;
    private SockJsClient sockJsClient = null;
    private WebSocketStompClient stompClient = null;

    private static class StompSessionChatHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
    }

    public Client() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        standardWebSocketClient =
                new StandardWebSocketClient();
        List<Transport> transports =
                new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(new WebSocketTransport(standardWebSocketClient)));

        sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

        stompClient =
                new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        String urlEndpoint = "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/chat-endpoint";

        this.sessionHandler = new StompSessionChatHandler();
        this.session = stompClient.connect(urlEndpoint, sessionHandler).get();
    }
}
```

And I get an error from the inside of Spring, something like the server url is incorrect; although the same url on the desktop java application is considered correct :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.hse.guidehelper, PID: 7048
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(UriComponentsBuilder.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsUrlInfo.getInfoUrl(SockJsUrlInfo.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.getServerInfo(SockJsClient.java:290)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.doHandshake(SockJsClient.java:260)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:270)
        at ru.hse.guidehelper.chat.Client.<init>(Client.java:103)
        at ru.hse.guidehelper.chat.DialogsActivity.addAllChatsInAdapter(DialogsActivity.java:71)
        at ru.hse.guidehelper.chat.DialogsActivity.onCreate(DialogsActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 96
    ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//(([^@\[/?#]*)@)?(\[[\p{XDigit}:.]*[%\p{Alnum}]*]|[^\[/?#:]*)(:(\d*(?:\{[^/]+?})?))?)?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
                                                                                                    ^
        at com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.compileImpl(Native Method)
        at com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.<init>(PatternNative.java:39)
        at com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.create(PatternNative.java:35)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1426)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1401)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.<clinit>(UriComponentsBuilder.java:97)
            ... 23 more
```

What could be wrong? Thank you in advance.

P.S. even `ws://localhost:8080/chat-endpoint` on android-client throws this error

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this problem, just change the version of the spring module you are using. It looks like it's a bug.

For example:

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
dependencies {
        constraints {
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
}
```